# hbm2hbmxml does not generate hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have search for this every where but couldnt find the answere 
i m following [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/tools-reference-3.2.0/ant.html) reference and used [this](http://www.newgoodidea.com/static/n5721.jsf) as a tutorial to write an ANT task to convert a POJO with ejb 3 annotations to a hibernate mapping file (hmb.xml)

My build ends successfully without errors but i cant found any hbm.xmk inside the target directory or any where

here is the code i used.

**build.xml**

```
<project basedir="." default="init" name="Test">

    <property name="sourcedir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="targetdir" value="${basedir}/bin"/>
    <property name="librarydir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>

    <path id="libraries">
        <fileset dir="${librarydir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${targetdir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean, copy-resources">
      <javac srcdir="${sourcedir}"
             destdir="${targetdir}"
             classpathref="libraries">
         <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
      </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="copy-resources">
        <copy todir="${targetdir}">
            <fileset dir="${sourcedir}">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
                <include name="**/*.properties"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java fork="true" classname="uk.co.pookey.hibernate.HibernateUtil" classpathref="libraries">
            <classpath path="${targetdir}"/>
            <arg value="${action}"/>
        </java>
    </target>

<taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="libraries" />


<target name="init" depends="clean, compile">
    <hibernatetool  destdir="${targetdir}">
        <classpath>
            <!-- it is in this classpath you put your classes dir, and/or jpa persistence compliant jar -->
            <path location="${basedir}/bin" />
        </classpath>
        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${basedir}/src/hibernate.cfg.xml" propertyfile="${basedir}/src/hibernate.properties"/>
        <hbm2dao destdir="${targetdir}"/>           
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

**POJO - Blog.java**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="blog")
public class Blog {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

    @Column(name="subject")
  private String subject;

    @Column(name="body")
  private String body;

    @Column(name="creatdate")
  private Date createdAt;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
  }

  public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
  }


  public String getBody() {
    return body;
  }

  public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
  }


  public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
  }

  public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }
}
```

**OUT PUT**

```
    init:
[hibernatetool] Executing Hibernate Tool with a Hibernate Annotation/EJB3 Configuration
[hibernatetool] 1. task: hbm2dao (Generates a set of DAOs)
[hibernatetool] 118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
[hibernatetool] 123 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.6.Final
[hibernatetool] 125 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.show_sql=false, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sahan, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}
[hibernatetool] 127 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[hibernatetool] 132 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[hibernatetool] 226 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from file: hibernate.cfg.xml
[hibernatetool] 308 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: java:hibernate/SessionFactory
[hibernatetool] 340 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
[hibernatetool] Jul 29, 2011 2:55:16 PM org.hibernate.tool.Version <clinit>
[hibernatetool] INFO: Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA
```

and the Jar files i used are

```
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
freemarker-2.3.1.jar
hibernate-tools-3.2.4.GA.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar
```

Please help me there is not much tutorials or working example sample codes for this task specially for generating hbm files from POJO s using annotationsconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to convert from annotations to XML config?  Many EJB3 annotations have direct Hibernate equivalents, or actually use the same annotation (`javax.persistence.*`).  I would just set up your project to compile against Hibernate and see what blows up, fix them, and move on.  Then you don't need to the XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found the reason :D
i didnt add mapping to the class in hibernate.cfg.xml file

previously it was

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetutorial</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">jndi/composite/name</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But it should be

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetutorial</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">jndi/composite/name</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!-- Mapping files of the class should go here  -->
  <mapping class="Blog"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

what is missing was "" part now it generate the Blog.hbm.xml file.